# Multimedia sound effects

Tags: design, effects

Hi guys, how can create multimedia effects like beeps,buttons,mouse over???

Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

I know some people started from microwave ovens beeps, but a signal generator should get you on the way. Rather than using sine waves, have a bash at triangular and sawtooth.

Is it for use in a movie or an actual application?

Also, because it is important to have a point of view from which to tackle your sound design, I suggest that you consider each sound as an auditory icon for the specific action it represents.

My 2 cents :)

Comment: Is just for practise! However I was thinking at multimedia sound for applications. For mouse I was thinking at the sound of power switch pitched up.

Comment: After that just experiment... For a mouse click, it physically sounds fast and abrupt, I wouldn't mind having a sound tailing out over a short period of time, but that smoothes out the end at least... Kinda like that: "fswou...". A little bit laser-style :)

Comment: You must have a mouse and keyboard if you're on this site. RECORD THEM!!! :)